# Creating new df from series of widget boxes

Tags: python, for-loop, ipywidgets

I have created an "input form" with several ipywidget boxes. I want to be able to reference all the values to create a new dataframe.
I'm currently doing this in a horrible way.

```
      portfolio_df = pd.DataFrame([[VBox1.children[0].value, VBox2.children[0].value, VBox3.children[0].value, VBox4.children[0].value]],
      columns=['Product Name','Units','Price', 'Invested Amount'])
      row_2 = [VBox1.children[1].value, VBox2.children[1].value, VBox3.children[1].value, VBox4.children[21].value]
      portfolio_df.loc[len(portfolio_df)] = row_2
      row_3 = [VBox1.children[2].value, VBox2.children[2].value, VBox3.children[2].value, VBox4.children[2].value]
      portfolio_df.loc[len(portfolio_df)] = row_3
      row_4 = [VBox1.children[3].value, VBox2.children[3].value, VBox3.children[3].value, VBox4.children[3].value]
      portfolio_df.loc[len(portfolio_df)] = row_4
```

and so on up till row 23 in this instance !! (but the length will vary up to the number of children within a VBox)

I suspect I can do this more pythonically using a for loop but cant figure it out.

Full code as per requests (I've edited columns so my live data is different but this is exact replica of the set up)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import ipywidgets as ipw
from ipywidgets import *


barrier_list = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(24, 4), columns=('Product 
Name','ISIN','A','B'))
barrier_list= barrier_list.astype(str)

dd_list = []
for i in range(len(barrier_list['Product Name'])):
    dropdown = ipw.FloatText(description=barrier_list['ISIN'][i],
                               value=barrier_list['Product Name'][i],
                               disabled=False,
                               layout = {'width':'350px'})
    dropdown.style.description_width = 'initial'

    dd_list.append(dropdown)

dd_list1 = []
for i in range(len(barrier_list['Product Name'])):
    dropdown1 = ipw.FloatText(description='Units',
                                value=0,
                           layout = {'width':'200px'})

    dd_list1.append(dropdown1)

dd_list2 = []
for i in range(len(barrier_list['Product Name'])):
    dropdown2 = ipw.FloatText(description='Price',
                                value=0,
                             layout = {'width':'200px'})

    dd_list2.append(dropdown2)

dd_list3 = []
for i in range(len(barrier_list['Product Name'])):
    dropdown3 = ipw.FloatText(description='Value',
                                value=0,
                             layout = {'width':'200px'})

    dd_list3.append(dropdown3)

VBox1 = ipw.VBox(dd_list)
VBox2 = ipw.VBox(dd_list1)
VBox3 = ipw.VBox(dd_list2)
VBox4 = ipw.VBox(dd_list3)
HBox = widgets.HBox([VBox1, VBox2, VBox3, VBox4])
```

Comment: Can you provide a more reproducible code? I would like to get all imports used on your snippets.

Comment: Yes hard without some setup code to help. But by the looks of it you need a container for your vboxes, like a list or a dict, then you could loop over them.

Comment: Full code now included - thanks for help !

Answer (score 0):

solved this one by looping through the VBoxes one by one and then concatenating the dataframes into one main one.

```
product_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(dd_list)):
    product_name_df =  pd.DataFrame([[VBox1.children[i].value]],columns= 
['Product Name'])

     product_df = product_df.append(product_name_df)

unit_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(dd_list)):
    unit_amount_df =  pd.DataFrame([[VBox2.children[i].value]],columns= 
['Units'])

    unit_df = unit_df.append(unit_amount_df)

price_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(dd_list)):
    price_amount_df =  pd.DataFrame([[VBox3.children[i].value]],columns= 
['Price'])

    price_df = price_df.append(price_amount_df)

value_df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(dd_list)):
    value_amount_df =  pd.DataFrame([[VBox4.children[i].value]],columns= 
['Value'])

    value_df = value_df.append(value_amount_df)

df_list = [product_df.reset_index(drop=True),unit_df.reset_index(drop=True),
price_df.reset_ind ex(drop=True),value_df.reset_index(drop=True)]   
portfolio_df = pd.concat((df_list), axis=1)
portfolio_df
```